# How to get the full Relation in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: laravel, relationship, eloquent-relationship

at the moment i try to learning Laravel and Laravel Eloquent.
I try to solve a problem using relations in Laravel.

I have following Database Structure in my simple Laravel Project.

```
table players:
id   name
```

```
table clubs:
id   name   icon
```

```
table players_x_clubs:
player_id   club_id
```

it's a one to many Relation.

Is it possible to get the full club Object who is combined with the player_id?!

The first try was to add this to my Player Model

```
public function club()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\PlayersXClub');
}
```

Here, i only get the PlayersXClub Relation with the player_id and the club_id

but i want to get the full club object from the club table, is it possible in a simple way?

any ideas how i have to realize is it correctly?

my solution was this:

```
public function getClubRelation()
{
    $clubRelation = $this->hasOne('App\PlayersXClub')->get()->first();
    $club = Club::whereId($clubRelation->club_id)->get()->first();
    return $club;
}
```

With this solution i can do this in my code `$player->getClubRelation()->icon`

but i don't know if its correct solved or is there a more simple way to resolve it with Eloquent?

Comment: You have a ManyToMany relation, use `hasMany` I guess for your relation

Comment: The way you set up your tables, it seems to me this is an manyToMany relation.

Comment: hm but 1 Player can only have 1 Club in my Case an 1 Club can have many Players...so One to Many is correct or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have access to objects relations. For example:

```
$player = Player::find(1);
$club   = $player->club;
```

or better

```
$player = Player::with('club')->find(1);
```

However, I believe you don't need an additional table. An additional table would result in a many to many relation which doesn't make much sense here.

A player belongs to a single club and a club can have many players. So it's one to many.

You should add a **club_id** foreign key to players table.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('club_id');
$table->foreign('club_id')->references('id')->on('clubs')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Player Class

```
public function club() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Club::class);
}
```

Club Class

```
public function players() {
   return $this->hasMany(Player::class);
}
```

Comment: ah okay! Now i understand it and you're so right Dino, i dont need the additional Table, right! Thx for open my eyes!